# Python adding extra backslash to string?

Tags: python, regex, escaping

I'm trying to create a regular expression to get an entry in an XML file however when trying to run my script `re.search()` returns `None` even though I verify the file contains the entry `characterCamos`.

This is my regular expression: `<characterCamos>(\d*)</characterCamos>`. However, the backslash gets escaped and it becomes this: `<characterCamos>(\\d*)</characterCamos>`. If I try to escape the backslash before entering it then it's still `<characterCamos>(\\d*)</characterCamos>`.

Either way this does not work and it doesn't capture the entry. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Can you use an XML parser?

Comment: @Rakesh To be honest I didn't even think about it. Now it's made my work so much easier. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using raw string instead. Raw strings do not treat the backslash as a special character at all. Every character you put into a raw string stays the way you wrote it.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm